# Trying to assign a string variable's value to another string variable in C#

Tags: c#, string, variables

I'm new to C# and trying to code a random number generator with assigned variables. main problem is that I can't assign the value of a string variable to the other, probably because of format. (if this is long winded, sorry, it's my first time on stack overflow.) here's the code:
edit: Thanks for the help, I'll go move the variable declaration now.

```
using System.Collections;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool Running = true;
        while (Running)
        {


            string item1;
            string item2;
            string item3;
            string item4;
            string item5;
            string answer;

            item1 = "";
            item2 = "";
            item3 = "";
            item4 = "";
            item5 = "";
            answer = "";


            Console.Write("Enter item 1: ");
            item1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter item 2: ");
            item2 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter item 3, or type null: ");
            item3 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (item3 == null) ;
            Running = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter item 4, or type null: ");
            item4 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (item4 == null) ;
            Running = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter item 5: ");
            item5 = Console.ReadLine();
            Running = false;

        }
        Random random = new Random();
        switch (random.Next(1, 6))
        {
            case 1:
                answer = item1;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you care to point out where in that code the issue actually is and also what it actually is, i.e. what actually happens? If there's an error message then keeping it a secret is not the way to get help.

Comment: This doesn't compile. You define the variables inside the loop and then try to use them *outside* the loop. Move the variable declarations outside the loop

Comment: If you want to access a variable outside the `while` loop, you have to declare it outside the while loop, e.g. at the top of the method.

Comment: In C#, stuff between a `{` and `}` pair is known as a _scope_.  You define the various `itemN` variables in the scope that belongs to the `while` statement.  Then you try to use them outside of that scope

Comment: `if (item3 == null) ;` doesn't do anything useful: the ; ends the statement (remove it)

Comment: I don't think Console.ReadLine will ever return a null, but it may return a empty string

Comment: @HansKeﬆing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I assumed the OP doesn't redirect input to a file, so then no null

Comment: @HansKeﬆing just tried to confirm `Console.WriteLine($"ReadLine:is null={Console.ReadLine()==null}");` (whole program) and Ctrl+Z (EOF) as input indeed printed "true".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ah, I didn't think about ^Z == end-of-file. I'll remember it now 

Answer (score 0):

you have a scope issue with you code, when you do a while loop (or any other function) the scope is set within the { }. This means that every variable declared within the {} of your loop is destroyed when the loop is done.

solution:
is to move declaration outside before the loop